# Unable to build AllJoyn JS Bindings & Compiler too old to build AllJoyn when building for Android

Tags: alljoyn

This is how I set up AllJoyn:

```
cd /opt
sudo mkdir alljoyn
sudo chown -R danny:danny alljoyn
cd alljoyn
repo init -u https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/devtools/manifest.git
repo sync
repo start master --all
```

Now, I would like to build AllJoyn js bindings, but getting Exceptions (c, cpp and java worked out of the box):

```
/opt/alljoyn/core/alljoyn$ scons BINDINGS=js GECKO_BASE=/opt/xulrunner-sdk
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++11 flag... (cached) yes
Using OpenSSL crypto
Building bindings: js
Building services: 
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping common unit test build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping About Service unit test build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_core unit test build
SQLITE_DIR not specified: skipping Security Manager sample program build
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
    [CXX-SH]  alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc: In constructor 'ReplyReceiver::ReplyReceiver(Plugin&, BusAttachment&, ProxyBusObject&, qcc::String&, qcc::String&, CallbackNative*, const NPVariant*, uint32_t)':
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: error: no matching function for call to 'qcc::ManagedObj<ReplyReceiver::_Env>::ManagedObj(ReplyReceiver*, Plugin&, BusAttachment&, ProxyBusObject&, qcc::String&, qcc::String&, CallbackNative*&, const NPVariant*&, uint32_t&)'
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:488:5: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedCtx*, T*) [with T = ReplyReceiver::_Env]
     ManagedObj<T>(ManagedCtx* context, T* object) : context(context), object(object)
     ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:488:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 9 provided
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:348:146: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8, class A9, class A10> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&, A6&, A7&, A8&, A9&, A10&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5, typename A6, typename A7, typename A8, typename A9, typename A10> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5, A6 & arg6, A7 & arg7, A8 & arg8, A9 & arg9, A10 & arg10)
                                                                                                                                                  ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:348:146: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 10 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:324:132: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&, A6&, A7&, A8&, A9&) [with A1 = ReplyReceiver*; A2 = qcc::ManagedObj<_Plugin>; A3 = qcc::ManagedObj<ajn::BusAttachment>; A4 = qcc::ManagedObj<ajn::ProxyBusObject>; A5 = qcc::String; A6 = qcc::String; A7 = CallbackNative*; A8 = const _NPVariant*; A9 = unsigned int; T = ReplyReceiver::_Env] <near match>
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5, typename A6, typename A7, typename A8, typename A9> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5, A6 & arg6, A7 & arg7, A8 & arg8, A9 & arg9)
                                                                                                                                    ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:324:132: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'ReplyReceiver*&' from an rvalue of type 'ReplyReceiver*'
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:301:119: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&, A6&, A7&, A8&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5, typename A6, typename A7, typename A8> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5, A6 & arg6, A7 & arg7, A8 & arg8)
                                                                                                                       ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:301:119: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 8 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:279:106: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&, A6&, A7&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5, typename A6, typename A7> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5, A6 & arg6, A7 & arg7)
                                                                                                          ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:279:106: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:258:93: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&, A6&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5, typename A6> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5, A6 & arg6)
                                                                                             ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:258:93: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 6 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:238:80: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&, A5&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename A5> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4, A5 & arg5)
                                                                                ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:238:80: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:222:67: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&, A4&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3, A4 & arg4)
                                                                   ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:222:67: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:204:54: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2, class A3> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&, A3&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2, A3 & arg3)
                                                      ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:204:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:190:41: note: candidate: template<class A1, class A2> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&, A2&)
     template <typename A1, typename A2> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1, A2 & arg2)
                                         ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:190:41: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:174:28: note: candidate: template<class A1> qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(A1&)
     template <typename A1> ManagedObj<T>(A1 & arg1)
                            ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:174:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:122:119: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
         env(this, plugin, busAttachment, proxyBusObject, interfaceName, methodName, callbackNative, npargs, npargCount) { }
                                                                                                                       ^
In file included from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30:0,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
                 from build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/BusAttachment.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.h:19,
                 from alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.cc:16:
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:133:5: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj() [with T = ReplyReceiver::_Env]
     ManagedObj<T>()
     ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:133:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 9 provided
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:113:5: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(const qcc::ManagedObj<T>&, bool) [with T = ReplyReceiver::_Env]
     ManagedObj<T>(const ManagedObj<T>&other, bool isDeep)
     ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:113:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 9 provided
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:91:5: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(qcc::ManagedObj<T>&) [with T = ReplyReceiver::_Env]
     ManagedObj<T>(ManagedObj<T>&copyMe)
     ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:91:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:83:5: note: candidate: qcc::ManagedObj<T>::ManagedObj(const qcc::ManagedObj<T>&) [with T = ReplyReceiver::_Env]
     ManagedObj<T>(const ManagedObj<T>&copyMe)
     ^
build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:83:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
scons: *** [build/linux/x86_64/debug/obj/alljoyn_js/jni/ProxyBusObjectHost.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

And when trying to build AllJoyn on Linux for my Android device it complains the compiler is too old:

```
/opt/alljoyn/core/alljoyn$ scons OS=android CRYPTO=builtin ANDROID_NDK=/opt/android-ndk-r13
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++11 flag... no
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++0x flag... no
*** Compiler too old to build AllJoyn.  Aborting.
```

I'm using the following compiler versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm really confused as from above the c++ compiler should have support for `-std=c++11` flag.

Notice: I've downloaded NDK r13 and had to create `/opt/android-ndk-r13/RELEASE.TXT` which contains `r13a` in order to pass the version check.

List of `/opt`:

```
$ ls /opt
alljoyn  android-ndk-r13  android-sdk-linux  android-studio  xulrunner-sdk
```

And btw: Setting up and building AllJoyn is a mess. Docs are outdated and contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

--Answer not related to the main topic-- I agree the documents are sometimes very confusing, and now since the merger is on the way there will be more cases of Documents being even more less updated.